# Hide Front-End Admin Bar Including 32 px Spacing

Tags: templates, css, page-template, admin-bar, admin-css

I have a custom template and I inserted the following snippet to get rid of the admin bar for the page:

```
function hide_admin_bar(){ return false; }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar' );
```

The problem is this still leaves a blank white empty bar at the top of the page with a height of 32px. Looking at core, I see this function but there is no way to disable it. I also tried overriding `html { margin-top: 0 !important; }` in my theme stylesheet to no avail since this is output on the page directly.

```
function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

Does anyone have a clean way to completely remove the admin bar from the top of a specific template page (plus the white space)?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the display status with [show_admin_bar function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)

```
<?php show_admin_bar( false ); ?>
```

Comment: This still has the 32px margin

Comment: @cdmckay it shouldn't. If you still observe margin it might be specific theme trying to account for toolbar in its style and no handling cae when it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Amit Mishra's answer resolves my problem, I have put my codes in the below, thanks a lot

Admin can see the admin-bar, other user can not.

This solution will not leave a top blank band with 32px in height. 
Other answers which only remove `_admin_bar_bump_cb` will leave a ugly blank band on top

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar_user');
function remove_admin_bar_user() {
    if (current_user_can('administrator') || is_admin() ) {
        show_admin_bar(true);
    }else{
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hackish but I found adding the below snippet inline just like WordPress core did the trick. I hate inline styles but life doesn't always produce lemonade :-S

```
/**
 * Hides the admin bar on a template page.
 */
function hide_admin_bar() {
    wp_add_inline_style('admin-bar', '<style> html { margin-top: 0 !important; } </style>');
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This to your function.php  it hide the admin bar from frontEnd

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar_user');

function remove_admin_bar_user() {
                if (current_user_can('administrator') || is_admin() ) {
                  show_admin_bar(false);
                }
            }
```

Comment: That tries to hide the admin bar on admin pages or on the front end for admin users only.

Answer (score -2):

I found this function which gets rid of the 32px 'bump' left over after using "show_admin_bar(false)"

```
remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
```

That seems to do the job!

Answer (score -3):

From version 3.1.0, WordPress decided to add a toolbar for logged in users on the display side that's about the site's theme.

And add default admin bar callback before `</head>`:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

To remove it, you can try:

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
    function remove_admin_login_header() {
        remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
    }
```